# Apache Tomcat7 not starting after adding Omnifaces and CDI?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-3, catalina

I am facing an error after adding the OmniFaces library, and adding the CDI (followed this [link](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html)) to Apache Tomcat 7, and I am using Maven.

How can I solve this problem?

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TTL-web]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)   ...
>
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start
>   component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TTL-web]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Caused by:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-001202: Error
>   parsing jndi:/localhost/TTL-web/WEB-INF/beans.xml     at
>   org.jboss.weld.xml.BeansXmlParser.parse(BeansXmlParser.java:126)  at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.parse(WeldBootstrap.java:131)
>     ...
>
> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber:
>   39; Premature end of file.    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>     ...
>
> Oct 08, 2015 12:28:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal
>
> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)  ...
>
> Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
>     ....
>
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Oct 08, 2015 12:28:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>
> SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8004]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)    ...
>
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start
>   component [StandardService[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more
>
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more
>
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more

Comment: Check for empty lines at the beginning of the beans.xml. Remove all empty lines and spaces at start.

Comment: there is no empty lines and spaces but I tried to remove this line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and now tomcat it's starting fine now, thanks @Joachim

Comment: Check this file jndi:/localhost/TTL-web/WEB-INF/beans.xml. Please post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from the `beans.xml`, this file must an empty file without empty lines and spaces

thanks for @Joachim